# De-serializing a Scala Class with a HashMap

Tags: java, scala, serialization, collections, hashmap

We want to serialize and de-serialize some Scala classes (to achieve Deep Copy of objects as suggested here http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code)

The issue we are facing is that the classes have several HashMap member fields. The key of the HashMap is a POJO - say `MyCustomKey` (**not a primitive type** like String / Int)

`myHashMap = mutable.HashMap[MyCustomKey, Double]`

The serialization of a Scala class with such a HashMap works fine but trying to de-serialize throws up `ClassNotFoundException` on the `MyCustomKey` class.

From whatever we have researched, it seems that this is not possible. Is it correct or is there some way?

Comment: I think you should look into more how you are actually using Scala. Typically you are working with immutable objects and do not need to create an identical copy. If you want to copy an immutable object look into implementing a copy() definition. 

Case classes already have this functionality.

Comment: Yeah we cant use case classes as they, as you said, are recommended to have immutable members (vals only, no vars). We need the members to be mutable so guess case classes is not something we can use here.